# Node.js setting up environment specific configs to be used with everyauth

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, everyauth

I am using node.js + express.js + everyauth.js. I have moved all my everyauth logic into a module file

```
var login = require('./lib/everyauthLogin');
```

inside this I load my oAuth config file with the key/secret combinations:

```
var conf = require('./conf');
.....
twitter: {
    consumerKey: 'ABC', 
    consumerSecret: '123'
}
```

These codes are different for different environments - development / staging / production as the callbacks are to different urls.

**Question:** How do I set these in the environmental config to filter through all modules or can I pass the path directly into the module?

**Set in env:**

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.set('configPath', './confLocal');
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.set('configPath', './confProduction');
});

var conf = require(app.get('configPath'));
```

**Pass in**

```
app.configure('production', function(){
  var login = require('./lib/everyauthLogin', {configPath: './confProduction'});
});
```

? hope that makes sense

Comment: Found a solution that is using some of the ideas from below, by having the module = function rather than an object I can evaluate process.env.NODE_ENV and return the correct object for the environment. A little messy but works.

Comment: Pardon the shameless self-promotion, but I wrote a module for node.js that will do this via separate files and a command-line switch: [node-configure](https://github.com/randolpho/node-configure)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

My solution,

load the app using

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

Then setup `config.js` as a function rather than an object

```
module.exports = function(){
    switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
        case 'development':
            return {dev setting};

        case 'production':
            return {prod settings};

        default:
            return {error or other settings};
    }
};
```

Then as per Jans solution load the file and create a new instance which we could pass in a value if needed, in this case `process.env.NODE_ENV` is global so not needed.

```
var Config = require('./conf'),
    conf = new Config();
```

Then we can access the config object properties exactly as before

```
conf.twitter.consumerKey
```

Comment: Why are you using new here?

Comment: I second @bluehallu. Is `new` necessary?

Comment: the equivalent in Windows would be SET NODE_ENV=development

Comment: Instead of doing `new`. I do following in the `config.js` .... `Config = function(){...}; module.exports = Config()`

Comment: What if I have 50 web servers in which case its going to be difficult to go on to each server to manually initiate the script

Answer (score 63):

You could also have a JSON file with NODE_ENV as the top level. IMO, this is a better way to express configuration settings (as opposed to using a script that returns settings).

```
var config = require('./env.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
```

Example for env.json:

```
{
    "development": {
        "MONGO_URI": "mongodb://localhost/test",
        "MONGO_OPTIONS": { "db": { "safe": true } }
    },
    "production": {
        "MONGO_URI": "mongodb://localhost/production",
        "MONGO_OPTIONS": { "db": { "safe": true } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain why you think this is better way to express configuration settings  (as opposed to using a script that returns settings). ?

Comment: I guess it doesn't make too much difference. Mentally, when I see JSON I think 'static data' vs when I see a JS file, I think there's some logic inside it. Also, another benefit of using .json type is that other languages can import the same file.

Comment: @VenkatKotra configuration is generally considered static, and therefore best expressed declaratively with things like json, yaml, ini, etc. Done imperatively, with a script that yields that state, sortof implies something _dynamic_ is happening, which would be bad.

Comment: Be aware that this method exposes credentials in source control.

Comment: can i make diffrence url for staging and production?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755852/nodejs-development-and-production-environment-config-file-loading

Answer (score 39):

A very useful solution is use the [config module](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config).

after install the module:

```
$ npm install config
```

You could create a **default.json** configuration file. (you could use JSON or JS object using extension .json5 )

For example

```
$ vi config/default.json

{
  "name": "My App Name",
  "configPath": "/my/default/path",
  "port": 3000
}
```

This default configuration could be override by environment config file or a local config file for a local develop environment:

**production.json** could be:

```
{
  "configPath": "/my/production/path",
  "port": 8080
}
```

**development.json** could be:

```
{
  "configPath": "/my/development/path",
  "port": 8081
}
```

In your local PC you could have a **local.json** that override all environment, or you could have a specific local configuration as **local-production.json** or **local-development.json**.

The full [list of load order](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#file-load-order).

**Inside your App**

In your app you only need to require config and the needed attribute.

```
var conf = require('config'); // it loads the right file
var login = require('./lib/everyauthLogin', {configPath: conf.get('configPath'));
```

**Load the App**

load the app using:

```
NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

or setting the correct environment with **forever** or **pm2**

**Forever:**

```
NODE_ENV=production forever [flags] start app.js [app_flags]
```

**PM2 (via shell):**

```
export NODE_ENV=staging
pm2 start app.js
```

**PM2 (via .json):**

process.json

```
{
   "apps" : [{
    "name": "My App",
    "script": "worker.js",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    "env_production" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

And then

```
$ pm2 start process.json --env production
```

This solution is very clean and it makes easy set different config files for Production/Staging/Development environment and for local setting too.

Comment: npm install config --save , it's not better?

Answer (score 21):

## In brief

This kind of a setup is simple and elegant :

**env.json**

```
{
  "development": {
      "facebook_app_id": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_id",
      "facebook_app_secret": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_secret",
  }, 
  "production": {
      "facebook_app_id": "facebook_dummy_prod_app_id",
      "facebook_app_secret": "facebook_dummy_prod_app_secret",
  }
}
```

**common.js**

```
var env = require('env.json');

exports.config = function() {
  var node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  return env[node_env];
};
```

**app.js**

```
var common = require('./routes/common')
var config = common.config();

var facebook_app_id = config.facebook_app_id;
// do something with facebook_app_id
```

---

**To run in production mode :**
 `$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

---

## In detail

This solution is from : **http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/09/26/bootstraping-a-node-dot-js-app-for-dev-slash-prod-environment/**, check it out for more detail.

Answer (score 5):

The way we do this is by passing an argument in when starting the app with the environment. For instance:

```
node app.js -c dev
```

In app.js we then load `dev.js` as our configuration file. You can parse these options with [optparse-js](https://github.com/jfd/optparse-js).

Now you have some core modules that are depending on this config file. When you write them as such:

```
var Workspace = module.exports = function(config) {
    if (config) {
         // do something;
    }
}

(function () {
    this.methodOnWorkspace = function () {

    };
}).call(Workspace.prototype);
```

And you can call it then in `app.js` like:

```
var Workspace = require("workspace");
this.workspace = new Workspace(config);
```

Comment: I would rather keep all the logic inside the app.js `app.configure('development` code, but will have a look to see if I can use this solution with that

Comment: Update to this answer: [Architect](https://github.com/c9/architect) is a dependency management framework that solves this in a way nicer way.

Answer (score 5):

An elegant way is to use `.env` file to locally override production settings. 
No need for command line switches. No need for all those commas and brackets in a `config.json` file. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/node-js-setting-environment-variables?nah=1#28821696)

Example: on my machine the `.env` file is this:

```
NODE_ENV=dev
TWITTER_AUTH_TOKEN=something-needed-for-api-calls
```

My local `.env` overrides any environment variables. But on the staging or production servers (maybe they're on heroku.com) the environment variables are pre-set to stage `NODE_ENV=stage` or production `NODE_ENV=prod`.

Answer (score 5):

Set environment variable in deployment server (ex: like NODE_ENV=production). You can access your environmental variable through process.env.NODE_ENV.
Find the following config file for the global settings

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"

const configs = {
    base: {
        env,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
        dbPort: 3306,
        secret: "secretKey for sessions",
        dialect: 'mysql',
        issuer : 'Mysoft corp',
        subject : 'some@user.com',
    },
    development: {
        port: 3000,
        dbUser: 'root',
        dbPassword: 'root',

    },
    smoke: {
        port: 3000,
        dbUser: 'root',
    },
    integration: {
        port: 3000,
        dbUser: 'root',
    },
    production: {
        port: 3000,
        dbUser: 'root',
    }
};

const config = Object.assign(configs.base, configs[env]);

module.exports= config;
```

"base" contains common config for all environments.

Then import in other modules like:

```
const config =  require('path/to/config.js')
console.log(config.port)
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: this should be ignored by git right because it contains sensitive info? If this file is ignored then how to include this file during deployment?

Comment: that's a very good question, in this case you can have environent specific file stored in respective servers. then while deploying just pull configs from local server.

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this in a much more elegant way with [nodejs-config](https://github.com/harishanchu/nodejs-config) module.

This module is able to set configuration environment based on your computer's name. After that when you request a configuration  you will get environment specific value.

For example lets assume your have two development machines named pc1 and pc2 and a production machine named pc3. When ever you request configuration values in your code in pc1 or pc2 you must get "development" environment configuration and in pc3 you must get "production" environment configuration. This can be achieved like this:

1. Create a base configuration file in the config directory, lets say "app.json" and add required configurations to it.
2. Now simply create folders within the config directory that matches your environment name, in this case "development" and "production".
3. Next, create the configuration files you wish to override and specify the options for each environment at the environment directories(Notice that you do not have to specify every option that is in the base configuration file, but only the options you wish to override. The environment configuration files will "cascade" over the base files.).

Now create new config instance with following syntax.

```
var config = require('nodejs-config')(
   __dirname,  // an absolute path to your applications 'config' directory
   {
      development: ["pc1", "pc2"],
      production: ["pc3"],

   }
);
```

Now you can get any configuration value without worrying about the environment like this:

```
config.get('app').configurationKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not something new. It's similar to what @andy_t has mentioned. But I use the below pattern for two reasons.

1. Clean implementation with  No external npm dependencies
2. Merge the default config settings with the environment based settings.

**Javascript implementation**

```
const settings = {
    _default: {
       timeout: 100
       baseUrl: "http://some.api/",
    },
    production: {
       baseUrl: "http://some.prod.api/",
    },
}
// If you are not using ECMAScript 2018 Standard
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/1251350
module.exports = { ...settings._default, ...settings[process.env.NODE_ENV] }
```

I usually use typescript in my node project. Below is my actual implementation copy-pasted.

**Typescript implementation**

```
const settings: { default: ISettings, production: any } = {
    _default: {
        timeout: 100,
        baseUrl: "",
    },
    production: {
        baseUrl: "",
    },
}

export interface ISettings {
    baseUrl: string
}

export const config = ({ ...settings._default, ...settings[process.env.NODE_ENV] } as ISettings)
```