# Replace a function with another function for testing

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have a function called `connectToMongo` that connects to a locally-running mongodb database `myapp`. I have another function which invokes `connectToMongo`. I would like to test this other function with mocha. However, I would like to make it so that, while testing, any calls to `connectToMongo` will automatically connect to my `myapp_test` database instead of my normal one.

Ideally (I think) I'd like to do something like this (where `connectToMongoTestingDatabase` connects to `myapp_test`):

```
var connectToMongo = require('./connectToMongo'),
    connectToMongoTestingDatabase = require('./connectToMongoTestingDatabase')
    registerUser = require('./registerUser');

testingLibrary.configureAlternateBehavior(connectToMongo, connectToMongoTestingDatabase);

it('should register a user', function (done) {

    registerUser({name: 'bob', password: 'password1'}, function (error, response) {
        connectToMongoTestingDatabase(function (error, database) {
            database.collection('users').findOne({name: 'bob'}, function (error, user) {
                expect(user).not.to.be.null;
                done();
            });
        });
    });

});
```

I have been trying to make sense of the Sinon.JS library. I can't tell whether spies, stubs or mocks would fulfill this need, nor what the equivalent of `testingLibrary.configureAlternateBehavior` would be.

I suppose I could also create some global variable called `global.MYAPP_TESTING`, set that to `true` before I start my tests, and in the implementation of `connectToMongo` I could connect to the `myapp_test` database if `global.MYAPP_TESTING` is true. That seems bad though.

What is the best way to substitute the behavior of one function for another in JavaScript unit testing?

Comment: This is often what the DI (Dependency injection) pattern is used for. Make a single-use set of functions you just `require()` in place of the mongo business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a unit test, then you should mock all external dependencies (functions, objects) used in your function and just check that they are called or got desired values.

To make possible integration testing in your ConnectToMongo function you should get the connection string to db from environment depending config.
So when you'll run the test you'll set environment to 'test' and get one config object, during development you may have another config object (which different settings) and on live environment a 3d config.
Check out this for more info on making environment dependent config:
[Node.js setting up environment specific configs to be used with everyauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332333/node-js-setting-up-environment-specific-configs-to-be-used-with-everyauth)

Comment: Ended up doing `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'` before running mocha, and then using a config script that sets the correct mongo url based on the value of `NODE_ENV`, and requiring that config in connectToMongo when connecting.