# Setting up environment-specific configurations using app.get('env')

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, application-settings

My question relates to [an old answer given on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059538/1022914) but with a small modification.

I'll try an keep it simple as possible.

Suppose my folder structure is the following

```
|-- controllers
    |-- File.js
    |-- and many more...
|-- routes.js
|-- app.js
|-- config.js
|-- env.json (same as one in the old answer)
```

Relevant files contains

**app.js**

```
const routes = require('./routes');

app.set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'); // set the environment
app.use('/', routes);
```

**routes.js**

```
const FileController = require('./controllers/File');

let router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/files', FileController.getFiles);

// ...

module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/File.js**

```
const config = require('../config');

exports.getFiles = (req, res, next) => {
    // I would like to use the environment-specific (that was set in app.js) config here
    console.log(config.facebook_app_id);
};

// ...
```

**config.js**

```
const env = require('env.json');

/*exports.config = function() {
    var node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    return env[node_env];
};*/

module.exports = env[app.get('env')]; // this would cause an error as app is not defined
```

This might be a silly question but how can I use the application setting i.e. `app.get('env')` within `config.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it would be to parse the `process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'` in your config file and then reference it when you instantiate your app.  Another thing to consider is using `process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'` instead so that devs have to explicitly say they are in a production environment.  You don't want to accidentally use production

```
const env = require('env.json')
module.exports = env[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production']
```

Comment: I was about to also comment on dev as default and not prod ;-)

Comment: So basically not to use application setting in the config file. My end goal was to have one place where I would do `process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'`. Though, according to the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set), the default value for `app.set()` is `process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'`. Since it's better to use `development`, I guess it works out. Thanks.