# nodeJS development and production environment config file loading

Tags: json, node.js, express, require

Based on this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22524056/777700 I have set exactly the same configuration options, but it doesn't work.

My (partial) app.js file:

```
console.log('environment: '+process.env.NODE_ENV);

const config = require('./config/db.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"];

console.log(config);
```

My ./config/db.json file:

```
{
    "development":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"3306",
        "username":"root",
        "password":"",
        "database":"dbname"
    },
    "production":{
        "host":"production-host",
        "port":"3306",
        "username":"user",
        "password":"pwd",
        "database":"dbname"
    }
}
```

Console.log outputs:

```
environment: development
undefined
```

and app crashes. Any idea why? File is there, if I remove the [...] part of require(), it does print out the db.json file, with it, it prints out undefined.

**EDIT**
I tried to add `console.log(typeof config)` just after require() to see what I'm getting and I have noticed that if I `require('./config/db.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV]` I get `undefined`, but if I `require('./config/db.json')["development"]` I get back proper object.

Versions:

```
nodeJS 6.11.4
express 4.16.2
```

Comment: Please tell me what you are trying because it seems like you haven't defined your NODE_ENV environmental value...

Comment: It should be in your bashrc file  or you can like this ```NODE_ENV=development node app.js```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more debugging and searching online, I have finally found the solution. The problem is that I'm on Windows machine and I was using `npm run dev` command while my "dev" command looked like `SET NODE_ENV=development && nodemon server.js`.

Experienced eye will notice a **space before &&**, which added a space behind the variable `development`, so the variable I was comparing against was `"development "` and not `"development"` as I was thinking.

So, the original answer from other question does work and it does load proper config!

Answer (score 0):

You should export configuration as a variable:

```
const config = {
    "development":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"3306",
        "username":"root",
        "password":"",
        "database":"dbname"
    },
    "production":{
        "host":"production-host",
        "port":"3306",
        "username":"user",
        "password":"pwd",
        "database":"dbname"
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

This way it will be found :)

Comment: simply use .js extension

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via JSON:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let localConfig

try {
    localConfig = JSON.parse((fs.readFileSync('./config/db.json', 'utf-8'))
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Could not parse local config.')
    localConfig = false
}

module.exports = localConfig
```

You could then add logic for production, if there's no local configuration `localConfig` will return false and you can look for environment variables injected at that point.

Update:

I see that you're giving the production config yourself, in that case you can just access the key you need based on the environment. Just import `localConfig` and use the keys you need.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use dotenv package for this

**npm i dotenv**

> Step 1: In package.json add this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon app.js"
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=prod nodemon app.js"
  },
```

> Step 2: Add .env.prod and .env.dev files

.env.dev

```
PORT=7200
# Set your database/API connection information here
DB_URI=localhost
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_DEFAULT=dbName
```

> Step 3: Add this in config.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

const result = dotenv;
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error;
}
const { parsed: envs } = result;
// console.log(envs);
module.exports = envs;
```

> Step 4: Use like this when needed

```
const {
  DB_URI, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DEFAULT,
} = require('../config');
```

Now if u want for development, run

```
npm run dev
```

For prod, use

```
npm run prod
```