# Set Config property based on deployment platform (dev, staging, qa, production) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

In Node.js, I want to set config property value **based on platform (dev, staging, qa, production) it will get deployed.**

So for example for dev and staging environment, I want to set value '234' 
And for prod, i want to set value '456'.

for deployment, i am using VSTS. 
Shall I make the use of deployment variables?

Answer (score 0):

For setting config property based, please take a look at this question: [Node.js setting up environment specific configs to be used with everyauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332333/node-js-setting-up-environment-specific-configs-to-be-used-with-everyauth)

In VSTS Release, you could use **environment scoped** value per environment.

> Share values across all of the tasks within one specific environment
>   by using environment variables. Use an environment-level variable for
>   values that vary from environment to environment (and are the same for
>   all the tasks in an environment). You define and manage these
>   variables in the Variables tab of an environment in a release
>   pipeline.
>
> *Source Link: [Custom variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch)*

If you want to change values, suggest you to use **[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)** task Visual Studio Team Services Build and Release extension that replace tokens in files with variable values.