# Setup app production and developent mode in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app, I want to set production and development in my `config.js` file.

For that I have all most set all thing but I'm still missing something.

I want to get config data like database credential from config file based on my development mode. If I upload on live then app will use live cred. On other hand if I used local then it should be use local cred.

```
module.exports = function () {
    console.log("Process env is ::: ", process.env.NODE_ENV);
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
        return {
            db : {
                host:'localhost',
                batabase:'dbname',
                username:'',
                password:''
            }
        }   
    } else {
        return {
            db : {
                host:'localhost',
                batabase:'dbname',
                username:'',
                password:''
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I have taken ref from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355493/8612835)

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: @Mazki516 I have update my question.

Comment: @khushboo still I cannot filter out a specific question from this post

Comment: @Kristianmitk I want to set dynamic config values in app. For that I have set this code. So by just one value changed, whole app will use live config data.

Comment: I understand that, but this still does not reveal a question. In other words: whats the reason for this post?

Comment: @Kristianmitk The reasone is while use `config.js` file in another file then I can't able to use data by `config.data.database`. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this way.

```
module.exports = (function () {
  process.env.NODE_ENV='development';
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
       // Config data of Live
  }else{
       //Config data of Local
  }
})()
```

This **works** for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

process.env refers to the Environment Variables exists at the time you start you nodejs app . (it's part of the os)

When you deploy to cloud , usually it's handled for you already (process.env.NODE_ENV = production) .
Some cloud providers even give you the option to control it via a GUI .

But for local environment , you can use .dotenv package .  (https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

With this package you create a .env file at the top of your project ,

and just write down NODE_ENV = local/staging/production

Please note that you can always run in shell:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

(WATCH FOR WHITESPACES !)
before you start you nodejs app which will also give you the effect
of controlling process.env

Using the config files in other files, just by requiring it .

```
const config = require('path/to/config.js');
```

then config.data.host will be changed depend on the NODE_ENV

Comment: I just want to use config data in otehr file as in my comment. `config.data.database`