# How to define environments for express server project?

Tags: node.js, express

I need my project to have different configurations as per environments, `production`, `development` & `local`.

I searched so two different suggestions are made by people:

1] Making use of env.json, [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332333/node-js-setting-up-environment-specific-configs-to-be-used-with-everyauth)

2] .env file ( Here I am not sure how to name file for prod & dev ), [See this npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-env-file)

I am confused about what is officially supported for express js server.

Comment: Official way is explained on official website : http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production

Comment: So process.env is official but how about loading different environments? I ended up using tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @pcj, you are using the right too ([dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)), check the doc for how to setup environment variables on various deployments and how to ignore `.env` file to githhub or other services like github.

Comment: @TheAlpha, Thanks, I have made changes as per the documentation provided by dotenv tool.